# problema de clases en python

Tags: python-3.x

El problema es que cuando voy a imprimir lo que hay en el metodo Validar me dice que necesita que le mande 3 parametros pero esos 3 parametros se los mando dos veces en el codigo

```
class Hora():
    def __init__(self,*args):

        if len(args)==3:
            self.horas=args[0]
            self.minutos=args[1]
            self.segundos=args[2]
            self.validar(args[0],args[1],args[2]) #Le mando a la funcion validar los tres parametros leido

        else:
            self.horas=0
            self.minutos=0
            self.segundos=0

    def leer(self):
        while(True): #Este ciclo se repite hasta que ingresen los datos correctamente
            try:
                self.horas=int(input("Digite la cantidad de horas (0-24): "))
                self.minutos=int(input("Digite la cantidad de minutos (1-59)"))
                self.segundos=int(input("Digite la cantidad de segundos (1-59)"))
                self.validar(self.horas,self.minutos,self.segundos) #Le mando a la funcion validar los tres parametros
                break 
            except:
                print("Datos incorrectos ingresalos nuevamente")

    def validar(self,horas,minutos,segundos):
        return self.validar

def main():
    hora=Hora() #Aqui guardo la clase en una variable
    print(hora.validar()) 
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

El error concreto por el que preguntas se debe a lo que haces en `main()`, donde tienes `hora.validar()`, y por tanto ahí la estás llamando sin pasarle los parámetros apropiados.

Pero aparte de eso tu programa tiene errores más graves. ¿Qué se supone que ha de hacer la función `validar`? Por su nombre uno esperaría que compruebe si la hora es un valor entre 0 y 23, y los minutos y segundos entre 0 y 60, pero no hace nada de eso. Simplemente contiene `return self.validar`, lo que no tiene ningún sentido puesto que `self.validar` es ella misma. Retorna una referencia a sí misma, y no realiza validación alguna.

Por otro lado, aún si hiciera validación ¿cómo informaría de si alguno de los datos está mal? ¿Debería retornar `False` en ese caso? Tal como tienes el programa tampoco serviría de nada, pues donde llamas a `self.validar()` no compruebas el valor que ésta retorna. Deberías usar algo del estilo `if not self.validar(...):` y hacer algo si los datos no son correctos.

Finalmente, aunque esto es ya un detalle menor, puedes simplificar mucho el constructor de la clase si en  lugar de pasarle `*args` haces uso de los parámetros con valor por defecto de Python. Así:

```
class Hora():
    def __init__(self, horas=0, minutos=0, segundos=0):
        if not self.validar(horas, minutos, segundos):
           print("Datos no válidos")
           self.horas = self.minutos = self.segundos = 0
           return
           # ... o lo que sea que tengas que hacer en este caso

        # Si pasa la validación, asignar
        self.horas = horas
        self.minutos = minutos
        self.segundos = segundos
```

Los valores por defecto te permiten omitir esos parámetros en el constructor, o darles un valor a alguno de ellos (o a todos). Por ejemplo: `Hora()` sería válido, y también `Hora(22)` (que dejaría minutos y segundos a cero), o  `Hora(15,20,25)` que especifica los tres valores.

Comment: Gracias amigo y si el programa esta incompleto no habia podido completarlo por este error que me daba